# Putting downloadable PDF file in my live html website

Tags: pdf, hyperlink

I have a portfolio site hosted by 000webhost, and I am trying to put my resume as a pdf file.  It works locally as I have the path, but I cannot get it to run live.  It is a pages document and I put the file on 000webhost and linked to it, but it doesn't open up.  Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

//  a href="files/Resume.pdf" target="blank" type="application/pdf">Download My CV

Answer (score -1):

**Easy HTML way to download files from your website**

```
<a href="/samanthaming.png" download>
  Download My Cv
</a>
```